# Basemap plotting a contour figure over coastlines

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to superimpose a contour plot onto a basemap plot of coastlines. Right now it either plots both separately or just the basemap.

```
Xa = np.linspace(-93.6683,-93.2683,25)
Ya = np.linspace(29.005,29.405,25)
plt.figure()
m = Basemap(width=1200000,height=900000,projection='lcc',resolution='f',lat_1=29.205,lat_2=29.5,lat_0=29.205,lon_0=-93,4683)
m.drawcoastlines()
plt.contourf(Ya,Xa,Result.reshape(len(Xa),len(Ya)))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The Result in the code are the concentrations that are plotted as a contour. I would add them, but there are 625 values for concentration from running my code. 
Im wondering how I can write the plotting part of my code to be able to superimpose the two graphs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use basemap's contour function here. This has however some particularities.

- It accepts only 2D arrays as input, meaning, you need to create a meshgrid of coordinates first.
- and the input must be the mapped coordinates, `x,y = m(X,Y)`

Also pay attention to the dimensions. The first dimension of a numpy array is the y axis, the second dimension is the x axis.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


Xa = np.linspace(-93.6683,-93.2683,25)
Ya = np.linspace(29.005,29.405,25)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(Xa,Ya)
Result = np.random.rand(len(Ya)*len(Xa))


m = Basemap(width=1200000,height=900000,projection='lcc',resolution='c',
            lat_1=29.205,lat_2=29.5,lat_0=29.205,lon_0=-93.4683)
m.drawcoastlines()

mx,my = m(X,Y)
m.contourf(mx,my,Result.reshape(len(Ya),len(Xa)))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to run the code the same way that you have above, I get the warning "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py:1540: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan. self.zmax = float(z.max())" and it doesn't print my contoured plot on the figure. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know. I don't get this error when running the code.